# What points satisfy $\frac{|z-i|}{|z+i|}<1$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing

Here's what I got so far

$$|z-i|<|z+i|$$
$$z^2-i2z-1<z^2+i2z-1$$
$$0<i4z$$

Comment: be careful, this is absolute value...):

Comment: in that case, if we are to square both sides would we have to write $|z-i|^2=(z-i)(z+i)$?

Comment: in that case inequality can't hold, since we'd get $1<1$.  Does that give us that no $z$ satisfy the equation?

Comment: @johnfowles `|z−i|^2=(z−i)(z+i)?` No, but $\,|z-i|^2 = (z-i)(\color{red}{\bar z}+i)\,$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geometrically $|z-i|=|z+i|$ shows all points which have the same distanse from $i$ and $-i$, they lie on $x$ axis so $|z-i|<|z+i|$ is the upper half plane.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $z$ is closer to ... than to ...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: set $z=a+bi$ in your last unequality and find the geometric properties $(a, b)$ should have.